# ¿Cuál seria la manera adecuada de implementar una función de recursión para este código?

Tags: javascript

tengo un par de días que me inicie en **Js** de manera autodidacta y quisiera ayuda para resolver este código.

Logré identificar si un nombre de usuario es válido o no y alerte en pantalla con cualquiera de los dos resultados, pero quisiera implementar la recursión para que cuándo el usuario sea "inválido", se tenga que escribir nuevamente hasta que sea válido.

```
const USERCHECK = /^[a-z][a-z]+\d*$|^[a-z]\d\d+$/i;
let validador = '';

while (validador == '' || validador == null) {

  validador = window.prompt('Ingrese su nombre de usuario');
}
alert(validador = USERCHECK.test(validador) ? 'Usuario válido' : 'Usuario inválido');


let usuarioNoValido = validador => {
  if (validador == true) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    return usuarioNoValido(validador)
  }
}
```

Lo intenté de esa manera sin conseguir un resultado, aprecio su ayuda y muchas gracias!.

Comment: Una disculpa, ya quedó la nueva edición,

Comment: Eso es un lambda. Creo que también se puede usar para recursión, pero lo más normal es usar funciones.

Comment: Mi lógica de programación aún no es muy buena y creí que esa seria una opción, lo intente de distintas maneras sin conseguir el resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes implementar la funcion `checkString(string)` y llamar a la misma recursivamente hasta que se ingrese una cadena que cumpla con la expresion regular:

```
const USERCHECK = /^[a-z][a-z]+\d*$|^[a-z]\d\d+$/i;

checkString(prompt('Ingrese su nombre de usuario'))

function checkString(mystring){
  if(USERCHECK.test(mystring)) alert('Usuario valido')
  else {
    alert('Usuario no valido')
    checkString(prompt('Ingrese su nombre de usuario'))
  } 
}
```

Comment: gracias!, desconocia la funcion checkString

Comment: es una funcion creada por mi mismo, puede tener cualquier nombre y nativamente JS no tiene dicha funcion, quizas la confusion surgio porque puse 'implementar LA funcion' como si fuese conocida por todos xd

Answer (score 1):

La manera adecuada sería hacerlo con funciones, mucho más simple.

Aquí, al llamar la función, le indico al usuario que ingrese un nombre. Una vez ingresado, verifico con la condicional si el valor ingresado no cumple con el `regex`, si esto ocurre muestro en un `alert` que el usuario no es válido y luego llamo nuevamente a la función `validar()`, aquí es donde ocurre la recursión. La recursión acaba cuando entra al `else`, ya que aquí solo muestro el `alert` diciendo que el usuario es válido y de ahí no hace nada más, por ejemplo:

```js
const USERCHECK = /^[a-z][a-z]+\d*$|^[a-z]\d\d+$/i;

function validar() {
  // le digo al usuario que registre un nombre.
  let nombreUsuario = window.prompt('Ingrese su nombre de usuario');
  // verifico si el nombre no es válido.
  if (!USERCHECK.test(nombreUsuario)) { // entonces, si se cumple esto...
    alert('Usuario inválido'); // menciono que no es válido...
    validar(); // y vuelvo a llamar a la función (aquí se aplica recursividad).
  } else { // y si el nombre del usuario es válido...
    alert('Usuario válido'); // solo muestro este mensaje y la función termina.
  }
};

validar();
```

Comment: Maldita sea, me ganaste de mano :(

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ no te preocupes, siempre es bueno tener varias alternativas (aunque se parezcan) :-).

Comment: bueno, pero la verdad es que es muy parecida, cambian algunas cosas nomas

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ si ya tenías la respuesta lista no pasa nada porque la publiques. Me pasó que estuve 10min escribiendo una y justo aparece otra así que para no desperdiciar mí trabajo lo publiqué igual.

Comment: Ambas respuestas ayudan a ampliar los conocimientos, muchas gracias!

Comment: Listo. Una disculpa :)